# Boxing and Performance

Tags: c#, .net

Could someone expand the spectrum of the samples of boxing and performance in .NET?

This sample is clear for me, but are there other cases?

*Code optimization flow*

**BAD CODE**

```
void CountVer1(int max)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} out of {1}",
            i, max);
    }
}
```

**GOOD CODE**

```
void CountVer2(int max)
{
    object maxObj = max;
    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} out of {1}",
            i, maxObj);
    }
}
```

**IDEAL CODE**

```
void CountVer3(int max)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} out of {1}",
            i.ToString(), max.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I was under the impression that in the first example, `WriteLine()` would just called `ToString()` on `i` and `max` anyway making it the same as the third example. Is that not the case?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko I am talking about the stack/heap staff and types of the.NET in sense of the performance, no more.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I need different examples of the code optimization in order to minimize heap usage.

Comment: From what I can see boxing is done in both `Bad code` and `Good code` they should have the same "performance" right?

Comment: The cost of the IO is going to outweigh the cost of the boxing by quite a bit.  This is not a context in which boxing *matters*.  The primary issue with boxing comes up when designing an API; you'll want to rely on generics to not box structs when passed to your methods.

Comment: Oh I see. The 1st differs from the 3rd in that the arguments are boxed when provided to `WriteLine`, whereas strings do not need boxing. So, *technically* the 3rd option would avoid the boxing. However, on the scale of performance I doubt this would be a noticeable issue.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, nice I didn't think about that. Even so, I think this questions a bit pointless, I can't see its purpose.

Comment: @Peretz No, it's not "shit".  You seem to think that boxing is really expensive.  **It is not particularly expensive**.  In this context it will account for a **very** small difference, certainly not something that's even worth thinking about for a 10 iteration loop.  When dealing with code that will execute a few tens of millions of times, doing multiple boxing operations per iteration, then perhaps it's a problem.  In this code though, it's certainly a micro-optimization.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` is *much* more expensive than boxing. I'd prefer the first code of your three examples since it's the cleanest code. To justify your other code variants you need to show the output of a profiler that shows that 1) This code is performance critical in the first place 2) Calling `.ToString()` manually is a significant performance hit. Without that evidence, it's just premature optimization.

Comment: @Peretz And so what.  If you could spend 5 minutes to earn 5 thousandths of a cent or you could spend that same five minutes to earn $20, would you go for the 5 thousandths of a cent instead?  You almost certainly have much bigger problems in your code if it's a sizable application.  Doing something like this will virtually never be the difference between an application that's fast enough and one that's not.

Comment: Got to agree with Servy here, we profile our (very) large WinForms app all the time, boxing has never been hot code. And we can avoid cussing surely. Don't forget, boxing has a place. It isn't "bad practice" in and of itself.

Comment: @Peretz It makes perfect sense. The only example of boxing you'll ever get is when someone tries to put a value type into a reference type. There are times when people don't seem to think it happens, like `Enum.HasFlags` for example, but the situation is always the same. If you spot a value type being put into a reference type argument or variable, it's boxed. Performance is entirely subjective. The CLR is very good at creating objects (ie, fast), and boxed items *tend* to be short lived, but usage dictates the effect of that. Good luck.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth That's sounds good and logically.

Comment: @Peretz It's not appropriate to just ask for "any code smaple that involves boxing" on SO.  That's simply not the format of questions that's considered appropriate here.  There's no concrete practical problem; there's no one right answer, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boxing is considered slow because it implies the allocation of an object. In your case that object is short lived (will probably not survive Gen0), which makes it cheap. A recent microbenchmark I did put the cost of generating a short lived object at about ~15 CPU cycles. Cost might be a bit higher in real applications, but that boxing isn't that expensive.

You should avoid  allocations in performance critical code. But that means code that's called >10 million times per second.

If you benchmark your above code, you'll see that `Console.WriteLine` is the expensive part, and that optimizing out those two boxes has negligible impact.

When optimizing a program's performance, I'd:

1. Profile to identify the bottleneck. But 99% of the code performance isn't an issue
2. Rewrite it to your hopefully better version
3. Profile it again, and verify that the performance improvement is significant. If it is not, revert to the simpler code, or try another variation.